# javascript on change using while loop

Tags: javascript

Error:

```
TypeError: d.options is undefined while(i<=d.options.length){
```

Hi i have this javascript of mine which has the select option to choose from. and from choosing from the select options it will display to the textbox field im using this onchange and using it while loop. can someone help me how to figure this out?? using while loop code?
Here's my code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Activity 2 while loop</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function tellMe(d){
      var i = 0;
      while(i<=d.options.length){
        if(d.listbox1.options[i].selected == true){
          d.choose.value = d.listbox1.options[i].text;
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="form1">
    <p>Girl's qualities you want?</p>
    <select name="listbox1" size="5" onchange="tellMe(this.form)">
      <option>Pretty</option>
      <option>Sexy</option>
      <option>Hot</option>
      <option>Intelligent</option>
      <option>Funny</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <p>
      You Choose: <input type="text" name="choose" />
    </p>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

any help is muchly appreciated! thanks

Comment: You aren't incrementing i.  You need to add i++ at the end of your while loop.

Comment: this is the error when selecting the select options
TypeError: d.options is undefined
 

while(i<=d.options.length){

Comment: use this instead of this.form.

Comment: this is the error when i change it to this
TypeError: d.listbox1 is undefined
 

if(d.listbox1.options[i].selected == true){

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8D53/)

Fixed it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Activity 2 while loop</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function tellMe(d){
        document.getElementById("choose").value = d.value;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="form1">
    <p>Girl's qualities you want?</p>
    <select name="listbox1" size="5" onchange="tellMe(this)">
      <option>Pretty</option>
      <option>Sexy</option>
      <option>Hot</option>
      <option>Intelligent</option>
      <option>Funny</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <p>
      You Choose: <input type="text" id="choose" name="choose" />
    </p>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

You were trying to get `this.form` but it should have been `this`, then the value of `this` (`this.value`).

Then, all you had to do was set the input type with `name='choose'`, however I gave it an `ID` of choose to make it easier to select, then gave that value `d.value`, which was the value of `listbox1`.

Comment: ive got this error when using your code
TypeError: d.options is undefined
 

while(i++<=d.options.length){

Comment: @bobcatnyxz Fixed it for you.

Comment: There doesn't have to be one in this version, it gets the text instead of going through each one to see which is selected instead. So it's now using less code and still working. @bobcatnyxz

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the form element, which doesn't have `options`. Change `d.options` to `d.listbox1.options`

```
while(i<=d.listbox1.options.length){
```

After that is fixed your second problem will become apparant, whch is that you fail to increment `i`:

```
 while(i<=d.listbox1.options.length){
     ...
     i++;
 }
```

Comment: Will create a new error since the OP uses the form for textbox

Answer (score -1):

You aren't incrementing i. You need to add i++ at the end of your while loop.  You also need to target listbox1 in your while loop.

```
function tellMe(d){
    var i = 0;
    while(i<=d.listbox1.options.length){  // <-- use d.listbox1.options.length
        if(d.listbox1.options[i].selected == true){
            d.choose.value = d.listbox1.options[i].text;
        }
        i++; // <-- add increment here
    }
}
```

Comment: no its not working got this error
TypeError: d.options is undefined
 

while(i<=d.options.length){

Comment: i change it this is the error
TypeError: d.listbox1 is undefined
 

if(d.listbox1.options[i].selected == true){